# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type string and Enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following code where `Model.VerticalType` contains string. I want to compare it with an `Enum` but I get error:

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and

`DGS.DGSAPI.UI.BusinessModels.Enums.VerticalType.Voice`

```
@if (Model.VerticalType == DGS.DGSAPI.UI.BusinessModels.Enums.VerticalType.Voice)
{
   <img src="@phoneWSource" />
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why your model can't have the enum as a field?

Comment: @Bauss Code is written by someone else and I don't have rights to change it. So I had to find a solution for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `.ToString()` on the enum value.

```
@if (Model.VerticalType == DGS.DGSAPI.UI.BusinessModels.Enums.VerticalType.Voice.ToString())
```

This will convert the enum to it's name, in this case `Voice`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Enum.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert from string to Enum value:

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(DGS.DGSAPI.UI.BusinessModels.Enums.VerticalType), Model.VerticalType, true) == DGS.DGSAPI.UI.BusinessModels.Enums.VerticalType.Voice
```

`true` means to ignore case while parsing

Comment: I actually like the `.ToString()` method more than this, because if the string is not a valid enum value it just does a string equality comparison and returns false instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: @caesay it depends on requirements very much I think. Sometimes, I need  strings `"EnumValue"`, `"enumValue"` and `"enumvalue"` are equal to real `EnumValue`. Additionaly, there is a method `Enum.TryParse` to prevent exceptions... so, it depends.

Comment: You can do case-insensitive string comparisons just as easily, so your `"EnumValue"` vs `"enumValue"` example is not really valid